# join table with itself and save result in view in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I've been trying to do this for a while now but it's not working for me.
I have a table with 2 columns,for example something like this:

**tbl**

```
source | destination
  0    |     1
  1    |     2
  3    |     7
  9    |     10
```

I'm trying to join the table with itself,where there exists a destination that's equal to a source, rename it's 2 columns to S0,S1, take only the destination column from the right joined table and rename it as S2, then save the result in a view.

On the example table, running the query should have this view:

```
S0   | S1  |  S2
0    | 1   |  2
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
SELECT tbl.source as S0,tbl.destination as S1 FROM tbl
JOIN
SELECT Hops.destination as S2 FROM Hops
ON tbl.S1=Hops.source
```

but it's not working. I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: What error message are you getting "it's not working" doesn't give us many clues :P

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first thing to understand is how a join works.  In general, when you select from 2 tables joined together, you will have only one select statement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.Col1=T2.Col1
```

Note that the `*` in this statement is selecting every column from both tables.  You could also specify columns as `T1.*, T2.*`, or more appropriately in most cases, `T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col2` or something along those lines.

I don't know the specifics of what you're trying to achieve, but I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Source AS S0, T2.Source AS S1, T2.Destination AS S2
FROM tbl AS T1
INNER JOIN tbl AS T2
  ON T1.Destination=T2.Source
```

Alternately, if you want to include records where Destination does not match any Sources, you might try

```
SELECT T1.Source AS S0, ISNULL(T2.Source, T1.Destination) AS S1, T2.Destination AS S2
FROM tbl AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl AS T2
  ON T1.Destination=T2.Source
```

(Edit: actually, I realize the SELECT clause could be simplified to `SELECT T1.Source AS S0, T1.Destination AS S1, T2.Destination AS S2`, because we've defined the JOIN such that T1.Destination and T2.Source are equal unless T2.Source is NULL (i.e. no matching record was found), but I will leave it in as illustrative of using ISNULL or COALESCE between two columns with an OUTER JOIN, which can be a useful construct.)